# DiffUtil - item inserted/removed, notify existing items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When an item is added or removed using `DiffUtil`, inside `android.support.v7.util.AdapterListUpdateCallback` only the `notifyItemRangeInserted(1, 1)` or `notifyItemRangeRemoved(1,1)` respectively is invoked, `notifyItemRangeChanged()` is not invoked. I set the positions on each of the views using `setTag(position)` but are not getting updated for the existing items. Wouldn't prefer to update items manually.

list update:

```
 private void updateItems(final List<Feed> newPosts) {
    List<Feed> olderPosts = new ArrayList<>(currentPosts);
    final CustomDiffCallback DIFF_CALLBACK = new CustomDiffCallback(olderPosts, newPosts);
    final DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(DIFF_CALLBACK, true);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that we can't use `setTag()` and `getTag()` for passing in position to the views. Since the main purpose of `DiffUtil` is to minimize the updations for views that haven't changed, the views that already have positions set on them cannot get through an updation pass hence would return stale positions. Though In my case, I had the custom listener in a separate class, the update part was a bit unusual. I had to get `getLayoutPosition()` of `ViewHolder`. Also can use `getAdapterPosition()` for the same.